# How can I find the equation of an ellipsoid that is formed by another known ellipsoid that is spin with an infinite speed about a given axis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trigonometry, algebraic-topology, rotations

I have an ellipsoid: x^2/a+y^2/b+z^2/c=1.

a,b,c are known constants, positive real numbers (c>b>a>0).

This ellipsoid spin in an infinite speed about the axis [v;w;u] and about its center of mass (uniform mass distribution).

How can I calculate the equation of the ellipsoid or other shape that is formed by this infinite speed rotation.

for example if the ellipsoid is rotated about [0;1;0] with infinite speed the formed ellipsoid will be:

x^2/c+y^2/b+z^2/c=1.

Comment: infinite speed, infinite rotation? what is that?

Comment: In general it's not even going to be an ellipsoid, it'll be a strange torus thing...

Comment: The outer bounds of the resulting shape will often have both convexity and concavity, depending on the original ellipsoid and the spin vector...